# How to optimize a HTTP client for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, optimization, httpwebrequest

I have created my own implementation (pretty straight forward) in order to talk to a REST-service. The code for GET requests can be found below. However, I would like to hear if there are some obvious pitfalls in my code that makes the requests perform worse than they could. They work decently at the moment, but I have a feeling I could have done a better job.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void Get<T>(string url, Action<Result<T>> callback, NetworkCredential credentials = null, JsonConverter converter = null)
{
    // Checks for no internet
    if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        callback(new Result<T>(new NoInternetException()));
        return;
    }

    // Sets up the web request for the given URL (REST-call)
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    // Makes sure we'll accept gzip encoded responses
    webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";

    // If any credentials were sent, attach them to request
    webRequest.Credentials = credentials;

    // Queues things up in a thread pool
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object ignore) =>
    {
        // Starts receiving the response
        webRequest.BeginGetCompressedResponse(responseResult =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Fetches the response
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(responseResult);

                // If there _is_ a response, convert the JSON
                if (response != null)
                {
                    // Gives us a standard variable to put stuff into
                    var result = default(T);

                    // Creates the settings-object to insert all custom converters into
                    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

                    // Inserts the relevant converters
                    if (converter != null)
                    {
                        if (converter is JsonMovieConverter)
                        {
                            settings.Converters.Add(new JsonMovieListConverter());
                        }
                        settings.Converters.Add(converter);
                    }

                    // Depending on whether or not something is encoded as GZIP - deserialize from JSON in the correct way
                    if (response.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding] == "gzip")
                    {
                        var gzipStream = response.GetCompressedResponseStream();

                        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(new StreamReader(gzipStream).ReadToEnd(), settings);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), settings);
                    }

                    // Close the response
                    response.Close();

                    // Launch callback
                    callback(new Result<T>(result));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // Deals with errors
            {
                if (ex is WebException && ((WebException)ex).Response != null && ((HttpWebResponse)((WebException)ex).Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    callback(new Result<T>(new UnauthorizedException()));
                }
                else
                {
                    callback(new Result<T>(ex));
                }
            }
        }, webRequest);
    });
}
```

In general this code should be quite self explanatory, but here's a few more facts:

- I am using [Delay's optimized gzip-decoder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2012/04/19/quot-if-i-have-seen-further-it-is-by-standing-on-the-shoulders-of-giants-quot-an-alternate-implementation-of-http-gzip-decompression-for-windows-phone.aspx), which provides me with the method `GetCompressedResponse()` (basically the same as the original method).
- I have created some JSON.net custom JsonConverter classes in order to deserialize my JSON correctly. These are fairly simple and doesn't affect performance.
- The Result-class is simply a wrapper class for my results (contains a Value and Error field)

Comment: Why don't you use HttpClient with async rather than Thread Pool?

Comment: Found that this worked well - is there a performance gain to be made by making this switch?

Comment: do some performance profiling

Comment: Not for performance, because under the hood HttpClient uses HttpWebRequest, but it provides you a built-in async method which is not needed to use ThreadPool, less code lines.

Comment: @Cuong Le - as far as I have read throughout the interwebs, the WebClient should be avoided at all cost on WP7 - it uses the UI thread to call the EndResponse event. Source: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/216188.aspx/1

Comment: What I meant is `HttpClient`, not `WebClient`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As of WP SDK 7.1, the WebClient callback events will be called on the thread that the WebClient was created on, not the UI thread (unless you create it there).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JSON.net, but is there a form that takes a stream or a streamreader rather than forcing you to read the entire string into memory first? That's rather wasteful if the streams could be large, though it'll make no difference if they're all small.

There's been a `HttpWebrequest.AutomaticDecompression` property that can simplify your code since 2.0 (in fairness, I'm always forgetting about that myself).

You can use the `CachePolicy` property to have the request use the IE cache, which can be a big saving if you'll hit the same URIs and the server handles it appropriately (appropriate max-age, correct handling of conditional GET). It also allows some flexibility - e.g. if your use has a high requirement for freshness you can use the `Revalidate` level so you'll always contact the server, even if the max-age suggests the server shouldn't be contacted, but you can still act on a 304 appropriately (presented to your code as if it were a 200, so you don't need to rewrite everything).

You could even build an object cache on top of this, where you use the `IsFromCache` method to know that whether it's safe to use the cached object, or if you need to rebuild it because the data it was built from has changed. (This is really sweet actually, there's the famous line about cache invalidation being a hard problem, and this lets us pass the buck for that hard bit down to the HTTP layer, while having the actual cached items living in the .NET layer and not needing to be deserialised again - it's a bit of work so don't do it if you won't have frequent cache hits due to the nature of your data, but where it does work, it rocks).

Comment: Jon - thanks for your well-written answer. However, there are some things you mention that are not available on WP7. First of all - the JSON.net framework does not support using a stream for decoding, only a string. The `HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression` and `CachePolicy` properties are not available on the WP7 (silverlight) platform. Nor is `Revalidate`. Thanks for your ideas though, every once in a while I wish I was developing on the full .NET framework.

Comment: Apologies. The problem with abbreviations is that sometimes since they're small the eye can skip over them, as mine skipped over WP7 in this case.